# jquery pass variable value outside of function

Tags: jquery, variables, global, each

I've got an unimaginably huge order form that I'm combing through for values and building an array from. Amongst other things, I've got some `each()` iterations that I need to extract values from, appending them to variables that are used afterwards. Problem is that the values are returning undefined, which I think is because they're being assigned within the loop.

Here's my logic:

- Declare variables
- loop through each

  - assign value to variable
- post to array

My understanding is that the variable declaration outside the function allows me to use it globally. Guess I'm wrong!

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/x7CL6/

Here's the code:

```
$('a').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();   

/* Declare Variables */

    var test = [],
        one,
        two,
        three,
        four,
        el,
        kind,
        val;

/* Loop through each paragraph */

    $('section').find('p').each(function(){

        el   = $(this);
        kind = el.attr('class');
        val  = el.html();

        if (val === '1'){

            one = val;
        } else if (val === '2'){

            two = val;
        } else if (val === '3'){

            three = val;
        } else if (val === '4'){

            four = val;    
        }
    });

    test.push({
        one: one,
        two: two,
        three: three,
        four: four
    });

    console.log(test);
});
​
```

Comment: @nnnnnn It would work, but then I'd have four objects in the array and I only want one, with the four attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"My understanding is that the variable declaration outside the function allows me to use it globally."*

A variable is global if its declaration is outside *any* function. In your case all of your variables are defined inside the click handler function, so all are accessible within it and any nested functions including your `each()` callback.

If the intention is that each click should add another object to the `test` array then you need to define `test` *outside* the click handler.

The reason your variables are undefined is because your if/else conditions are always false so the variables never get assigned a value. Your `val` variable gets assigned the html content from the current element of the loop, and the html content is never equal to the `"1"`, `"2"`, etc., strings that you compare it to.

I think you probably intended to compare to each element's class attribute instead, which you've put in the `kind` variable:

```
if (kind === "1")
```

and so forth: http://jsfiddle.net/x7CL6/4/

...but given that you seem to be processing the elements in document order you could make use of the fact that jQuery passes your `.each()` callback the index of the current element:

```
$('section').find('p').each(function(i){ // add i param
    // inside the loop test i (note it starts with 0)
    // instead of testing val or kind
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x7CL6/2/

However that still leaves you with an ugly if/else if/... structure that you could avoid like this:

```
var test = [],
    propNames = ["one","two","three","four"],
    obj = {};

$('section').find('p').each(function(i){
    obj[ propNames[i] ] = $(this).html();
});

test.push(obj);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x7CL6/5/

Comment: The Fiddle was an oversimplification and the conditions returning false was just my sloppy typo. Apologize for that. Otherwise, based on your explanation and adjusting my fiddle it seems like my logic is solid. which means i'll need to hunt down the difference inbetween it and the program I'm working on. drag! thanks for your help.